# Codeigniter JQuery load data in view dynamically after jquery .get request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have been thinkering around and I cant get it to work. So i have a Jquery function which after input field onblur event posts new discount value in database.

JQuery:

```
    function saveAtlProc(t){
    pzid = $('#pzrows').attr('rel');
    atl_proc = $(t).val();
    var site_url = document.getElementById("site_url").value;
     $.post(site_url, {
            pzid : pzid,
            atl_proc : atl_proc,
            site_url : site_url
        },
        function(rawdata){
             getPZtotals();
        });
}
```

This works and is okey, the problem starts with getPZtotals(),

getPZtotals() JQuery:

```
function getPZtotals(){
pzid = $('#pzrows').attr('rel');
var site_url = document.getElementById("pvn_rates_get").value;
$.get(site_url, {
        pzid : pzid
    },
    function(rawdata){
     var pieg_nos = rawdata.pieg_nos;
        alert(pieg_nos);
});
}
```

Alert function shows that the variable is undefined. And i cant figure out why.

This is what is returned in .get() inspecting it with firebug

```
[{"ID":"123","avr":"0","avrnr":"1502193","avrdat":"2015-03-15","avrproc":"0.00","pz":"","serija":"","numurs":"","datums":"0000-00-00","parvad":"P\u0101rvad\u0101t\u0101js: klienta transports","apm_not":"","apm":"","piez":"Jauns pied\u0101v\u0101jums","pieg_id":"667","pieg_nos":"Miks Ratnieks SIA","reg_nr":"RE\u0122ISTR\u0100CIJASNR","pvn_id":"PVNSNR","pieg_jadr":"Uliha 68-1","pieg_fadr":"Kurmja pieg\u0101des32-1","pieg_iban":"LV34012389072345987","pieg_swift":"SWED8927348","pieg_banka":"SWEDBANK","valuta":"EUR","summa":"300.00","atl_proc":"2.00","atl_summa":"6.00","summa_bpvn":"294.00","pvn":"63.00","summa_arpvn":"363.00","apm_datums":"0000-00-00","datetime":"2015-03-19 13:04:22","avanss":"","avanss_txt":"","avanss_sum":"0.00","avanss_apm":"0.00","arpvn":"","komentars":"","nol":"","statuss":"Iesakts","autors":"","pvn_summa_0":"0","pvn_summa_1":"0","pvn_summa_2":"0","pvn_likme_0":"0","pvn_likme_1":"21","pvn_likme_2":"12","pvn_0":"0","pvn_1":"0","pvn_2":"0"}]
```

I think that this is correct and there shouldnt be any problems.

MY Controller: which returns data in .get() function

```
  public function get_new_discounts(){
    $this->load->model('offers_for_clients_model');
    $id = trim($_GET['pzid']);
    $data['orders_info'] =  $this->offers_for_clients_model->get_offers_info($id);
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data['orders_info']));
    /*echo ();*/
}
```

Model:

```
function get_offers_info($id){
    $query = $this->db->where('ID', $id)->get('pz_pied')->result();
    return $query;
}
```

I googled it but couldn`t find anything similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(rawdata);
alert(myObject[0].pieg_nos);
```

Comment: Obviously, the server returns strings. You could also use `.getJSON()` instead of `.get()`, which will parse the JSON (will apply `JSON.parse()`) before entering the `success()` method. You could also set the type of the data to receive using `dataType`. Read the documentation/search in Google... http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0):

Your php model is returning an outer array wrapping the object data you are trying to access in your alert.

Try:

```
 var pieg_nos = rawdata[0].pieg_nos;
 alert(pieg_nos);
```

Comment: Still getting undefined alert.

Comment: what do you see in console if you do `console.log(rawdata)`? Also try setting dataType to `'json'` and/or set response header

Comment: console.log. returns all the same as i mentioned above.

Comment: one is for passing the data to database and the other one is so i can retrieve the data i want afterwards, isnt that the correct way of doing it?

Comment: @charlieftl the dataType isnt working and still undefined, where should i put the response header? O.o

Comment: no, can return data needed in one request. Are you sure you are getting data for both?

Comment: set header at server for application/json

Comment: After first request i have to do some calculations and thats why i thought that it would be necessery to do two requests after the data is changed. I dont have access to server. Is there some other way?

Comment: by `@ server` I mean in php. Even if  header not set , setting dataType works. Not sure why you are having issues to be honest